# Declare input parameters for function-type in parameter declaration using typing

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

**Context**

Assume a function taking in a function like this:

```py
def some_func(
        parameter_1: str
        , func: function
    ):
    pass
```

As can be seen `func` shall be a function passed to `some_func`.

Anyhow, `func` shall be a function taking in a specifc parameter-type:

```py
def func(
        specific_parameter_of_type_string: str
    ):
    pass
```

**Question**

How do I declare in `some_func()` that the parameter `func` shall be a function which takes in a `str`?

I looked into the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)-module but did not find the solution to my question. Anyhow, I think it should be solvable with it...

The result would resemble something like this I assume:

```py
import typing

def some_func(
        parameter_1: str
        , func: typing.Function[str] # Example! This does not exist in typing
    ):
    pass
```

Comment: @not_speshal: Sorry, but this is not a solution to this problem - Casting is something entirely different than type hinting.

Comment: "`func` shall be a function taking in a specifc parameter-type"

Comment: Are you looking for [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable)?

Comment: @not_speshal: Yes exactly, and this is not declared by casting but by typing :)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Yes I was :) Encountered this also in the moment you wrote :D

Answer (score 0):

Reading the typing documentation more carefully I encountered that functions are actually referred to as `typing.Callable`s as can be read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable).

Thus, this can be used to specify both, the return type and input arguments:

> Callable[[Arg1Type, Arg2Type], ReturnType]

The solution is then:

```py
import typing

def some_func(
        parameter_1: str
        , func: typing.Callable[[str], None]
    ):
    pass
```